# Pasting Text Vertically Into .CSV File

Tags: csv, awk

I have this awk script to write a text file to a specific cell in a .cvs file, but I am trying to have the text displayed vertically, not horizontally.

```
`nawk -v r=2 -v c=3 '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","
}
FNR == NR {
    val = sprintf("%s%s%s", val, NR > 1 ? " " : "", $0)
    next
}
FNR == r {
    $c = val
}
1' file new_one.csv`
```

Want

```
the  
text  
like   
this
```

Comment: Paste some data from your input file and how you like that to be displayed.

Comment: input file -> This is contents of input file. 
desired output file -> This
is
contents
of
output
file.

Comment: I was asking you to put some data from that file in to your question.

Comment: in the awk script posted, there is a file named "file". It contains the words "This file has words horizontally". I'm trying to get each word stacked vertically in the same cell. Hope that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @JimmyF if you want to get best answer sooner, post input **example**(instead of description) and the expecting output.  You gave a "doesn't work" script, and let us guess what it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like:

```
val = sprintf("%s%s%s", val, NR > 1 ? " " : "", $0) + '\n'
```

Documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html)

Comment: This is only putting the value "0" in r=2, C=3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a csv input file like:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
k,l,m
```

and the data you want vertically like:

```
This file has words horizontally
```

here's one way to modify your script:

```
NR==FNR {gsub(" ","\n"); val="\""$0"\""; next}
```

This is going to replace all the single spaces in `$0` with newlines.  Then the whole line is assigned to `val`, but wrapped in double quotes per [wikipedia's csv page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples).

Running this with the data files I created from the command line (using a slightly different syntax used than you for `FS/OFS`):

```
awk -F"," -v r=2 -v c=3 'NR==FNR{gsub(" ","\n"); val="\""$0"\""; next} FNR==r {$c=val} 1' OFS="," vert data
a,b,c
d,e,"This
file
has
words
horizontally"
g,h,i
k,l,m
```

where `vert` is the name of the vertical data and `data` is the name of the csv data file.  Notice that `f` at `[2,3]` has been replaced with the altered input from the `vert` file.

Be aware that the row/column indexing you've chosen only works if none of the fields in the `data` file have internal commas in them and that `awk` isn't going to be your best friend for parsing csv files in general.